# Titanium Studio's new Alloy mobile project doesn't start

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Just after installation of Titanium Studio (Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-master-197 (origin/master) Date: 26 September 2014, 12:28:18) I created new Alloy mobile project and tried run it (Mobile Web Preview in Browser). Project doesn't execute, in console I see error:

...longjohn.js:185
        throw e;
              ^
TypeError: Bad argument
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:880:24)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:680:9)
    at async.parallel.powershell (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\windows.js:385:14)
    at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:524:25
    at C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:111:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:32:24)
    at async.each (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:110:9)
    at _parallel (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:523:20)
    at async.parallel (C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:539:9)

I have Win7 x64, java 1.7 x86, node 0.10.13, ADT 23.0.2 I tried different versions of titaium sdk (3.3), node.js but nothing helps.

Please, help. What should I try additional things or should I report some more info? 
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suggested workaround:

On this line: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/3_3_X/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/windows.js#L377

(likely in C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\windows.js)

Replace:

if (!selectedVisualStudio) return next();

with:

return next();

this workaround is taken from https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17411